# When to use the word "prototype" in adding new properties to an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I don't understand in JavaScript when to use the word "prototype" vs. using simple "dot" notation without the word "prototype". Can someone look at these code blocks and help me understand when you'd want to use one over the other?

**with** "prototype":

```
function employee(name,jobtitle)
{
  this.name=name;
  this.jobtitle=jobtitle;
}

var fred=new employee("Fred Flintstone","Caveman");
employee.prototype.salary=null;
fred.salary=20000;
console.log(fred.salary);
```

**without** "prototype":

```
function employee(name,jobtitle,salary)
{
  this.name=name;
  this.jobtitle=jobtitle;
  this.salary=salary;
}

var fred=new employee("Fred Flintstone","Caveman", 20000);
console.log(fred.salary);
```

Comment: Adding members to the `prototype` property of the constructor function makes sense if the member is a method - instead of defining the common methods on each instance, you simply put it in the prototype and all instances inherit them.

Comment: If I may suggest you, I would probably mark the @Mark Reed's answer as correct one as he explains it better than anyone else. It's probably possible to still change the correct answer somehow. But it's just a suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript objects have a property which is a pointer to another object. This pointer is the object's prototype. Object instances by default share the same prototype:

```
function Employee(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Employee.prototype.company = "IBM";

Employee.prototype.who = function(){
  console.log("My name is", this.name, "I work for", this.company);
}

var bob = new Employee('Bob');
var jim = new Employee('Jim');

// bob and jim are seperate objects, but each is linked to the same 'prototype' object.

jim.who(); // jim doesn't have a property called 'who', so it falls back to it's 'prototype', where who exists
// My name is Jim I work for IBM

bob.who();
// My name is Bob I work for IBM

// Bob leaves IBM for Microsoft
bob.company = "Microsoft"; // bob now has a property called 'company'. The value of which is 'Microsoft', which overrides bob's prototype property of the same name.

bob.who();
// My name is Bob I work for Microsoft

Employee.prototype.company = 'Facebook';

jim.who(); 
// My name is Jim I work for Facebook

bob.who(); // Bob is not affected by the change.
// My name is Bob I work for Microsoft

delete bob.company;

bob.who(); // bob no longer has it's own property 'company', so like jim, it drops down to the prototype object.
// My name is Bob I work for Facebook
```

Comment: So, is this analogous to a static method or variable?

Answer (score 9):

The issues around JS and inheritance may be complex, but the answer to your question is relatively simple.  Consider this code:

```
 function Klass() { }
 var obj1 = new Klass();
 var obj2 = new Klass();
```

Now, if you add a property to `obj1`, that property exists only on `obj1`.  Likewise `obj2`.

If you add a property to `Klass`, that property likewise exists only on Klass (the function object).  It doesn't affect `obj1` and `obj2` at all.

But if you add a property to `Klass.prototype`, that property will then be present on both `obj1` and `obj2`, as well as any future objects created via `new Klass`.  If you then change the value of the property on the prototype, the changed value will be what you see on all those objects.

You could add code inside the body of the `Klass` function to add properties to `this`; that will then cause any future `Klass` objects to get those properties.  But each object would have its own copy - which can add up, memory-wise, especially when the properties are methods -and those copies would not be affected by future changes to the body of `Klass`.

Comment: hi Mark, thanks, i think you're answer most directly answers my question. There are so many good answers, i'm torn on which one to accept. If you wouldn't mind, let me take a few hours to think about that...

Answer (score 3):

ES5's `Object.create` almost removes the need to hassle around with `.prototype` anymore.

So, to pick up @Gerry's example, you can go like

```
var Mammal = {
    walk: function() {}
};

var Dog = Object.create(Mammal, {
    bark: {
        value: function() {}
    }
}); // create a new object which [[prototype]] refers to Mammal

Dog.walk();
Dog.bark();
```

Comment: hi jAndy, what's the logic behind this new syntax?

Comment: @timpeterson: actually, you can inherit from objects without constructor functions, like shown above. You can still use constructor functions in combination with `Object.create` of course to have a somewhat more advanced and sophisticated inheritance. In generell, `Object.create` will create a new object and points that `.prototype` to the object you pass in as first argument, second argument is an object where you can create additional "own" properties. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: `var Dog = extend({}, Mammal, { bark: function() {} })`

Comment: @Raynos: I actually would love to see another answer refering to pure OC concepts.

Comment: @jAndy It's not really OC, it's just mixins.

Comment: Whales would disagree with this example.

Answer (score 1):

The `prototype` object is a little tricky to understand; however [this article on OOP JavaScript](http://killdream.github.com/blog/2011/10/understanding-javascript-oop/#sec-3-1) can help shed some light.

In a nutshell, the `prototype` object provides a blueprint for a 'recipient' object - all you have to do is point the recipient's `prototype` property at your blueprint object.  Note that you can have as many recipients of a prototype blueprint object as you like (so Car and Train can both point to a common Vehicle prototype object).

You are free to define both properties and functions in a prototype object which will any recipient objects will be able to use, eg:

```
var vehiclePrototype = {
    // A property which will be supplied to the recipient
    cost: 0,

    // A method which will be supplied the recipient
    move: function () { 
        // Your prototype can refer to 'this' still.
        console.log("Moving " + this.name);
    };
}
```

You can now create a `Car` which makes use of the `vechiclePrototype`:

```
// Factory method for creating new car instances.
function createCar(name) {
    // Define the Car's constructor function
    function Car(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Point the car's prototype at the vechiclePrototype object
    Car.prototype = vechiclePrototype;

    // Return a new Car instance 
    return new Car(name);
}

// Create a car instance and make use of the Prototype's methods and properties
var mustang = createCar(mustang);
mustang.cost = 5000;
mustang.move();
```

A new Train object could be created in a similar fashion:

```
function createTrain(whilstleSound) {
    // Define the Train's constructor function
    function Train(name) {
        this.whilstleSound = whilstleSound;
    }

    // Point the train's prototype at the vechiclePrototype object
    Train.prototype = vechiclePrototype;

    // Return a new Train instance 
    return new Train(name);
}

var ic125 = new Train("pooop pooop");
ic125.move();
```

One of the big advantages of using Prototypical inheritance all instances of both `Car` and `Train` share the exact same `move` function (instead of creating multiple instances of the same function) which results in a significant memory saving if there are many instances of these objects.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore `new`, ignore `.prototype` they are just confusing notions. If you really want prototypical inheritance use `Object.create` but most of the time inheritance is completely overkill. (prototypical inheritance should only be used as an optimization technique).

When building classes just create objects and extend them.

```
var Walker = {
    walk: function() {}
}

var Eater = {
    eat: function () {}
}

var Dog = extend({}, Eater, Walker, {
    bark: function () {},
    sniffBehind: function () {}
})

function dog(dogName) {
    return extend({}, Dog, {
        name: dogName
    })
}

var steveTheDog = dog("steve")
console.log(steveTheDog.name === "steve")
```

Use any arbitrary arity extend function you want, `_.extend`, `jQuery.extend`, [`pd.extend`](https://github.com/Raynos/pd#pd.extend), etc.

[pd](https://github.com/Raynos/pd) implements `extend` as follows

```
function extend(target) {
    [].slice.call(arguments, 1).forEach(function(source) {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source).forEach(function (name) {
            target[name] = source[name]
        })
    })
    return target
}
```

Comment: thanks Raynos, so I need to use `_.extend` or `$.extend` in addition to just `extend` or as a replacement for the native `extend` function?

Comment: @timpeterson there is no native `extend` function, you need to use some library that implements extend. I've inlined pd's extend implementation.

Answer (score 0):

With prototype, you can extend in a 'cleaner' way, because you are separating the logic inside your constructor function from the properties and methods that define your object.

```
var Mammal = function() { ... };
Mammal.prototype = {
  walk: function() { ... }
};

var Dog = function() { ... };

for (var prop in Mammal.prototype) {
  Dog.prototype[prop] = Mammal.prototype[prop];
}

Dog.prototype.bark = function() { ... };
```

However, the above without prototype could look like this:

```
var Mammal = function() {
  this.walk = function() { ... };
};

var Dog = function() {
  Mammal.apply(this);
  this.bark = function() { ... };
};
```

This way of extending Objects is however made irrelevant by modern JavaScript libraries like Underscore.js, or could be written much cleaner with the help of for example jQuery too.

Comment: Your example will add the `bark` method to `Mammal.prototype`, so all instances of `Mammal` will be able to bark, instead of all instances of `Dog` (I'm assuming you intended only dogs to be able to bark).

Comment: i'm also a little confused on what a constructor actually is. Is this the constructor, `var Mammal = function() { ... };`? If so, why isn't that just called an "object"?

Comment: @timpeterson A constructor is just a regular JavaScript function, the only difference is how it is invoked, which is with the 'new' keyword.

Comment: which begs the next question, when to use the word, "new" vs. not when making a function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word `prototype` to define some functionality across the application for particular type (Array, Function, Number of custom type)

For example you can extend all arrays with property `sum`:

```
const arrayPrototype = Array.prototype
Object.defineProperty(arrayPrototype, 'sum', { 
   get() { return this.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) }
})
```

When you've executed the chunk of code, all arrays have the property:

```
console.log([1,3,-1,10].sum) // prints 13
```