# Is it possible to access the prototype object of function by its function itself

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, constructor, prototype

for example

```
//creating constructor function

function Something(){}

//adding name property to Something prototype


Something.prototype.name='javascript';
```

is it possible to access name property from its object itself?

//like

```
Something.name

// but here output will be 'undefined'
```

**// code**

```
function Fan(){}

Fan.prototype.speed='high';

Fan.speed

//output of (Fan.speed) undefined
```

Comment: Please provide relevant Code Snippets of what you have so far.

Comment: Well, `Something.prototype.name`. It is only looked up from `o.name` to `o.prototype.name` on *instances* of that class/constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get the name of the currently running function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/q/10430794/125981

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss No man

Comment: You need to add more details to your question as to why it is different other than "no" as there seem to be answers already for your limited example.

Comment: Please explain why you are looking to do this so we understand your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of the object and then access it:

```js
function Something() {}
Something.prototype.name = 'javascript';
// create an instance for that
var x = new Something();
console.log(x.name);

//Another set of examples, note the prototype on the objects function has no instance so the getName.protytppe.bucket
const another = {
  secret: "skim",
  name: "cream",
  getName: function() {
    return this.name;
  },
  getSecret: function() {
    return this.secret;
  },
  makeButter: function(n) {
    this.name = n;
    return `We made {this.name} from cream`;
  }
};
another.getName.prototype.bucket = "lot-o-milk"

var n = Object.create(another);
console.log(n.name);
console.log(n.getName());
// make cream into butter
n.name = "butter";
console.log(n.name);
console.log(n.getName());
// turn butter back to cream
delete n.name;
console.log(n.name);
console.log(n.getName());
n.makeButter('yellow');
console.log(n.getName());
console.log(n.getSecret(), n.getName.prototype.bucket);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, if you set it up as `Fan.prototype.speed`, then that value is on `Fan.prototype.speed` and not `Fan.speed`. When you use `Fan` as the constructor of an object, that's when the instantiated object is set up with a lookup chain to look up properties that it doesn't have on the constructor's `prototype`:

```
const f = new Fan();
console.log(f.speed);  // lookup to Fan.prototype.speed
```